# Measurable, bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and irrational number

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, irrational-numbers

I want some tips how to prove that fact:

> Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable and bounded and $l_{1}\left(A\right)>0$. Show that there exist $a, b\in A$ that $a-b$ is irrational number.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Any thoughts yourself?

Comment: @Henry I think I can prove that this set must be at least of power of the continuum, then it will be very simple. But this fact is not that easy to prove and I completely don't have idea how to do that.

Comment: It is a well known result that $l_1(A)>0$ implies $(-a,a) \subset A- A$ for some $a>0$.

Comment: I don't know how it would help me.

Comment: @MateuszWójcik, it would then follow by Kavi's response that $A-A = \{a-b: a, b\in A\}$ contains an interval and thus an irrational number, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose not.  Fix some $a_0 \in A$.  Then by our supposition, $a_0 - a$ is rational for every $a \in A$.  In other words, $A \subset \{q - a_0 : q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.  But the latter is countable...